# Array.sort does not reorder array with NaN values in object

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a simple case with reordering items in array by prop `minLVL` of each `object` in it.

But for some reason it works only if the previous and the next ones props are present (as you can see not each `object` has required `minLVL` field). So, if the `minLVL` is missing in some object it does not reoder such item to the bottom of the list, it just stay in the same position instead.

How can I solve it? Thanks

Example:

```js
 var h = [
        {
            ID: 172
     },
        {
            ID: 179,
            minLVL: "30"
     },
        {
            ID: 169
     },
        {
            ID: 173
     },
        {
            ID: 167,
            minLVL: "25"
     },
        {
      ID: 175,
            minLVL: "10"
     }
    ]
    
          var n = h.sort((a, b) => Number(b.minLVL) - Number(a.minLVL))
    
    console.log(n)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can default those values to `0` if it does not exist inside the sort function:

```js
var h = [{
  ID: 172
}, {
  ID: 179,
  minCrimeLevel: "30"
}, {
  ID: 169
}, {
  ID: 173
}, {
  ID: 167,
  minCrimeLevel: "25"
}, {
  ID: 175,
  minCrimeLevel: "10"
}]

var n = h.sort((a, b) => (Number(b.minCrimeLevel) || 0) - (Number(a.minCrimeLevel)|| 0))

console.log(n)
```

Comment: Thank you. Yes, I know it. But it harms perfomance... Why JS does not make such calculation "under the hood", like with `undefined` values do?

Comment: @MaxTravis because `NaN` is a special value - `NaN > 0`, `NaN < 0`, and `NaN == 0` are all evaluated to `false` because `NaN` *is* (a bit paradoxically) a number but signifies a value that...isn't a number. `undefined` is *not* of type number, hence it gets coerced to one. There is nothing to coerce with `NaN`.

Comment: Agree with @vlaz. Check that you have used `Number()` function

Comment: but if you have zero as value, then this fails. you need an explicit check for `isNaN` or better check if `minCrimeLevel` is in the object and then take a big negative number as value, like `-Infinity`.